# Problem with ordering headings in a sorted list

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-lists

I am building a web application in which I build a sorted list out of an object like this:
`{head: {subhead: [list_items], subhead: [list_items]}, head: {subhead: [list_items]}}`.
My problem is that I have to ensure the headings and subheading always follow in a certain order.  This is complicated by the fact that headings and subheadings that may be added later on also need to follow this order.  So the only way I could think to inform the parser of the order would be to give it some data like this:
 `{heads: [head1, head2, head3], subheads: {head1: [subhead1_1, subhead1_2], head2: [subhead2_1, subhead2_2, subhead2_3]}}`,
but that strikes me as overly verbose and repeating data that would be in the original data structure.

Comment: This seems a little convoluted. Perhaps you should tell us the type of problem you're trying to solve, maybe we can suggest a better data structure that way.

Comment: I'm trying to create a series of lists sorted into headings and subheadings (e.x. '{food: {fruit: [apples, oranges], vegetables: [carrots, peas]}, animals: {domestic: [cat, dog], wild: [lion, bear]}}') in which the headings and subheadings follow a certain order. So I always want food to be listed before animals and within food I want vegetables before fruit. I suppose my problem arises from the fact that associative arrays (objects in this case) , are inherently unordered, so I need a way of giving order to them or a different way to express my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might as well use an array (or your own structure) for this since you want it to be ordered. Your own structure might look like:

```
function Head(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.arr = [];
}
```

So instead of the structure:

```
var thing = {
  food: {fruit: [apples, oranges], vegetables: [carrots, peas]},
  animals: {domestic: [cat, dog], wild: [lion, bear]}
}
```

You might do:

```
var thing = [new Head('food'), new Head('animals')]
```

Then:

```
thing[0].arr.push('apples'); 
thing[0].arr.push('oranges');
```

etc.

Of course you don't have to make a class, since you can actually attach properties to arrays in javascript. But making the datastructure would be a bit more of a pain.

Comment: Thank you so much! That object structure can be replicated with arrays and objects like so: {head: [{subhead: [items]}, {subhead: [items]}]}, which solves the problem of JSON serialization!